# What is the charge on the copper ion in antlerite?

Tags: ions

Antlerite is $\ce{Cu3(SO4)(OH)4}$.

I'm trying to get the charge on the copper ion in this substance.  So far I have the mass of $1$ mole of antlerite, its percent oxygen content, and the number of individual hydroxide ions in a $\pu{955 mg}$ bead of the substance, if that information helps at all.

I need help to solve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is a short answer. Since you already know the chemical formula it's actually quite easy provided you are familiar with the process of determining the oxidation numbers in chemical compound. From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antlerite) (and the way the chemical formula is written indicates that too) you can get the information that the $\ce{SO4}$ part of the formula is sulfate and sulfate ions carry a charge of $-2$, i.e. $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$. Furthermore, in most cases $\ce{H}$ gets an oxidation number of $+1$ and $\ce{O}$ gets an oxidation number of $-2$ so that the 4 $\ce{OH}$ units in the compound each have a charge of $1 - 2 = -1$, so you have $\ce{OH^{-}}$, i.e. hydroxyl groups - this is supported by the way those $\ce{O}$'s and $\ce{H}$'s are grouped, if you see "$\ce{OH}$" in a compound it usually means "hydroxyl group". So, you have one sulfate group with a charge of $-2$ and four hydroxyl groups with a charge of $-1$ each, giving you a charge of $-6$ in total. But your compound $\ce{Cu3(SO4)(OH)4}$ is neutral, i.e. has a charge of $0$, so the three $\ce{Cu}$ have to counteract the negative charge exerted by the anions, in other words you have to distribute a charge of $+6$ between the three copper atoms. If you assume that the charge is evenly distributed, i.e. that all the $\ce{Cu}$ are the same (this need not necessarily be the case, you can also have mixed oxides like $\ce{Fe3O4}$ where you have $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ and $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ within the same mineral), you get to a charge of $+2$ for each copper ion, i.e. $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$.